# Unavailable websites return weird path instead of normal path “http://www.xn--”nameofwebsitehere"-zsd.com/

Tags: browser, internet, website, redirection, hyperlink

Whenever I type any website badly on purpose, for example if I write in any browser `www.youareadamnfool.com` I get the following `http://www.xn--youareadamnfool-zsd.com/` in the url bar (so it actually changes in the urlbar) instead of getting back `www.youaredamnfool.com`. I do not know since when this happens but it is very weird for me and I am not sure why this happen.

Anybody knows why? Thanks

Comment: looks like a browser hijack. Run your malware scanner.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name#Example_of_IDNA_encoding)?

Comment: Does it lead to an actual webpage, or just to a "domain not found" error? Can you show a few more samples? ("xn--" indicates Punycode, and your example decodes to `www.youareadamƎnfool.com`.)

Comment: Mates, it only happens from time to time. https://i.imgur.com/HEfHLuu.png -> example. Also excuse me the irreverence... but I typed into the urlbar in spanish "mierdapoliciaviolandoespañolas" and it returned http://www.xn--mierdapoliciaviolandoaespaolas-34c.com/ -> so actually it does not seem to like the spanish letter "ñ"

Comment: Another website http://xn--respondiendopreguntasenespaol-w1c.com/ -> I typed respondiendopreguntasenespañol.com

Comment: Also it seems it only happens like 1 time every 4 I write any unavailable website. I don´t know but it also seems to happen when writing the word Ñ. Hmmm for example ñ.com brings back http://xn--ida.com/  omiting the ñ altogether.

Comment: Internet fells down and https://i.imgur.com/hYxn2nk.png -> Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapters are added without me touching anything... :/

Comment: Well, your _new_ examples seem completely normal – that is indeed how non-ASCII domains with a `ñ` are stored in DNS. (See Kamil's Wikipedia link.) It's just the first one that is slightly off.

Comment: Yeah unavailable websites throw off randomly those punicode things... and my bios is listed as being from 2032... if I believe biosagentplus...